# Site re-directs to login page even after a successfull login

Tags: uri, redirection

Presently I am using the Windows Server on which the drupal 7.34 is installed with the xampp server.

The url for the site is `localhost:8081/example`

When I enter the URL(`localohost:8081/example`) to login, the page simply re-directs to the login page

[image: Page re-directs showing the login block at the left of the page even after a successful login]

Whereas when I enter the complete URL (the IP address along with the port number it loads the site)

[image: Entered the complete IP Address along with the port no then the page loads with ease]

Now I can't figure out why the page is redirecting me to the login page but not the main page when I am entering the `localhost:portno/example`

[update][image: On entering the URL from my system it gives that the following IP address is banned.]

Things Tried:-

1.Pinged the IP address and it was successful with no loss.

2.Tried it on a different browser Internet explorer got Error HTTP Error 403 Forbidden.

3.Tried on a different system with the same IP address and in that system the site loads fine.

4. Re-installed the drupal software again with the same localhost:portno/

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is normal

The default front page of Drupal is this one. It displays the latest published and promoted nodes. If you want to put another node as a front page you can do it in configuration>site information

Also drupal assumes that your site is in the top level directory (e.g. yourserver:port/)
If you want to change it to yourserver:port/custompath/ then set the $base_url to custompath in your settings.php file

Comment: say The regular url is http://localhost:8080/example/ shall load the default page(image 1 with the left block as login,password),then even the http://192.168.21.11:8080/example/ which I enter in the server should also load the same default page(image 1) then why the difference?(the ip address which is the same example should also load the image 1 but not image 2).I have checked the settings.php fileand the $base_url = 'http://www.example.com';  is the same for default settings as well as settings